# Play Framework: Dependency Inject Action Builder

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

since Play Framework 2.4 there is the possibility to use dependency injection (with Guice).

Before I used objects (for example `AuthenticationService`) in my ActionBuilders:

```
object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    ...
    AuthenticationService.authenticate (...)
    ...
  }
}
```

Now `AuthenticationService` is not an object anymore, but a class. How can I still use the `AuthenticationService` in my `ActionBuilder`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Define your action builders inside a trait with the authentication service as an abstract field. Then mix them into your controllers, into which you inject the service. For example:

```
trait MyActionBuilders {
  // the abstract dependency
  def authService: AuthenticationService

  def AuthenticatedAction = new ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
    override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block(AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      authService.authenticate(...)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

and the controller:

```
@Singleton
class MyController @Inject()(authService: AuthenticationService) extends Controller with MyActionBuilders {    
  def myAction(...) = AuthenticatedAction { implicit request =>
    Ok("authenticated!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to add `val` before `authService` in `MyController` otherwise the compilator complains that the authService method was not defined

Comment: This does not work for me with either a val or a def, says the Controller class needs to be abstract because def/val not defined

Answer (score 18):

I didn't like the way one was required to inherit in the above example. But apparently it's possible to simply wrap a `object` inside class:

```
class Authentication @Inject()(authService: AuthenticationService) {
  object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      // Do your thing wit the authService...
      block(request)
    }
  }
}

class YourController @Inject() (val auth: Authentication) extends Controller (
  def loggedInUser = auth.AuthenticatedAction(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like accepted answer but for some reason the compiler would not recognize the authService reference. I got around this pretty easily by just sending the service in the method signature, a la...

```
class Authentication @Inject()(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) extends Controller with ActionBuilders {

  def testAuth = AuthenticatedAction(authenticationService).async { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok("Authenticated!"))
  }

}
```

Comment: I just checked and I see no reason the accepted answer would not compile!