# Get cache API @Inject() in ActionBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an `ActionBuilder` LoggingAction that executes in every request:

```
object LoggingAction extends ActionBuilder[Request]{
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    Logger.info("Logging some things")
    block(request)
  }
}
```

Now, I need to access the cache API in the LoggingAction object (the one that extends `ActionBuilder`. However, in Play 2.5.x, the cache object is obtained through injection only in the class that extends `Controller`:

```
class ProcessLogin @Inject() (cache: CacheApi) extends Controller  {
      //...
}
```

I need to access the cache API in the `ActionBuilder` object, but I cannot inject it because it doesn't extend `Controller`. Is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE

One option could be to inject at field level, but it doesn't work as the field remains `null` when the cache API is used:

```
@Inject val cache: CacheApi = null
```

Comment: See very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098911/play-framework-dependecy-inject-action-builder

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question, it helped

Comment: The second answer worked for me, see `Play Framework: Dependecy Inject Action Builder`